# Can we allow both back-slashes and forward-slashes in Stack Exchange mark-down language tags?

Tags: feature-request, markdown

I like that the super-user site supports a limited subset of HTMl tags.

One of the supported HTML tags is `<kbd>` tags for <kbd>keyboard</kbd> text.

Given that Stack Exchange mark-down language is ***not*** HTML, Stack Exchange mark-down tags can do things with HTML tags which HTML tags cannot.

My feature request would be that forward-slashes and backslashes be interchange-able in Stack Exchange mark-down language tags.

---

## Example One

- `<kbd>keyboard</kbd>` <kbd>keyboard</kbd>
- `<kbd>keyboard<\kbd>` <kbd>keyboard</kbd>

---

## Example Two

An example is shown below.

```
> 1. Select all of the text on a page by pressing <kbd> Ctrl </kbd> + <kbd> A <\kbd>      
>     
> 2. Copy the text 
>     
> > to copy text press the control-key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd> C <\kbd> at the same time.   
>
> 3. Paste the text into a word processor such as Microsoft Word, [office libre][2]
>  
> > to paste text press the control-key <kbd>Ctrl<\kbd> and <kbd> V </kbd> at the same time.   
>   
> 4. Print it as ink on a sheet of physical paper.
```

---

## Example of Rendered Output

**How to Print a Stack Exchange Post**

> 1. Select all of the text on a page by pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>A</kbd>
> 2. Copy the text
>
> > to copy text press the control-key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and  <kbd>C</kbd>  at the same time.
>
> 3. Paste the text into a word processor such as Microsoft Word, [Office Libre](https://www.libreoffice.org/)
>
> > to paste text press the control-key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and  <kbd>V</kbd>  at the same time.
>
> 4. Print it as ink on a sheet of physical paper.

Comment: What is the point of this? In any case ``\`` may be used as an escape character so it would just be confusing to support `<\key>`

Answer (score 5):

Stack Exchange *primarily* uses [CommonMark](https://commonmark.org) - and there's a specification for the [use of raw html within it](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#raw-html)

While a subset is supported - its supported within the specification. I currently Stack Exchange also uses a pair of markdown renderers that are [open source and support these standards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark), so allowing for the \ replacing the / is unlikely.